# Filebeat v.8 cannection dial up error i/o timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I can't connect filebeat with elastisearch via API
this is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: true
    reload.period: "10s"


processors:
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0600

filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths:
    - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  multiline.type: pattern
  multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})[[:space:]]+\b|^java.lang.RuntimeException:'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
  multiline.max_lines: 200  
  encoding: utf-8

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
      - type: docker
        templates:
        - condition:
              equals:
                docker.container.image: febbweiss/java-log-generator:latest
        config:
          - type: container
            multiline.type: pattern
            multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})[[:space:]]+\b|^java.lang.RuntimeException:'
            multiline.negate: false
            multiline.match: after
            paths:
              - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.docker.container.id}/*.log
            encoding: utf-8




output.elasticsearch:
 # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["172.28.0.2:9200"]
  api_key: "xnE9XIsBbiDPznkqk0yw:OKQhJBC4SqCYKeM0BMXxfw"
  loadbalance: true
  protocol: "https"
  ssl:
    enabled: false
```

When I test output
 `./filebeat test output -c ./filebeat.yml --path.home /usr/share/filebeat --path.data /var/lib/filebeat`

```
elasticsearch: https://172.28.0.2:9200...
  parse url... OK
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: 172.28.0.2
    dial up... ERROR dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9200: i/o timeout

and log result
Connect to 172.28.0.2:9200 [/172.28.0.2] failed: Connection refused\\\", :exception=>Manticore::SocketException, :cause=>#<Java::OrgApacheHttpConn::HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.28.0.2:9200 [/172.28.0.2] failed: Connection refused>
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-10-23T11:50:13.846Z","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"transport/logging.go","file.line":38},"message":"Error dialing dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9200: i/o timeout","service.name":"filebeat","network":"tcp","address":"172.28.0.2:9200","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"debug","@timestamp":"2023-1023T11:50:13.846Z","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":271},"message":"Ping request failed with: Get \"https://172.28.0.2:9200\": dial tcp 172.28.0.2:9200: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```